# skipping incompatible /libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to "make" ioquake3 on IBM machine.
But, I kept getting the "skipping incompatible /libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL" error.
I am thee ultimate beginner at Linux, but not a quitter!
I have no privileges to install any libraries, and our server admin is not responding for about a week now. So, I've been googling/testing for for a solution now.
As the message said, the library that is on the system is incompatible. So, I went to the Ubuntu site, and downloaded SDL PPC library freshly.
I uploaded, unpacked it into a designated folder.
However, GCC doesn't know where those libraries are. So, I found something called "LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/pkgs/usr/lib"
 to tell GCC where my libraries are.
However, everytime I do a "make", I do not my "export" folder in the list.

Please help, even with a different way, just to fix my incompatible SDL library problem.

below is the output:

```
<pre>rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean[7188]% echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/pkgs/usr/lib
rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean[7189]% cd ~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/pkgs/usr/lib
rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/pkgs/usr/lib[7190]% ls
libSDL.a  libSDL.la  libSDL.so@  libSDLmain.a  libopenal.a  libopenal.so@  pkgconfig/
rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/pkgs/usr/lib[7191]%</pre>

<pre>rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean[7174]% make
make[1]: Entering directory `/r/home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean&#39;

Building ioquake3 in build/release-linux-ppc64:
  PLATFORM: linux
  ARCH: ppc64
  VERSION: 1.36
  COMPILE_PLATFORM: linux
  COMPILE_ARCH: ppc64
  CC: cc

  CFLAGS:
    -MMD
    -Wall
    -fno-strict-aliasing
    -Wimplicit
    -Wstrict-prototypes
    -pipe
    -DUSE_ICON
    -I/usr/include/SDL
    -D_GNU_SOURCE=1
    -D_REENTRANT
    -DUSE_OPENAL
    -DUSE_CURL
    -maltivec
    -Icode/SDL12/include
    -m64
    -DUSE_MUMBLE
    -DUSE_VOIP
    -DFLOATING_POINT
    -DUSE_ALLOCA
    -Icode/libspeex/include
    -DUSE_LOCAL_HEADERS
    -DPRODUCT_VERSION=&quot;1.36&quot;
    -DNDEBUG
    -O3
    -ffast-math
    -funroll-loops
    -fomit-frame-pointer

  LDFLAGS:

  LIBS:
    -ldl
    -lm

  Output:
    build/release-linux-ppc64/ioq3ded.ppc64
    build/release-linux-ppc64/ioquake3.ppc64
    build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/cgameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/qagameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/baseq3/uippc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/cgameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/qagameppc64.so
    build/release-linux-ppc64/missionpack/uippc64.so

make[2]: Entering directory `/r/home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean&#39;
make[2]: `build/release-linux-ppc64/ioq3ded.ppc64&#39; is up to date.
LD build/release-linux-ppc64/ioquake3.ppc64
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libSDL.so when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../libSDL.so when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libSDL.so when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [build/release-linux-ppc64/ioquake3.ppc64] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/r/home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean&#39;
make[1]: *** [targets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/r/home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean&#39;
make: *** [release] Error 2
rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/svfb_201110271440/ioquake3dev_clean[7175]% ls</pre>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` determines the search path for shared libraries on runtime. What you want is to say where the library is on compile time. You can use `LDFLAGS` for this - with the `-L` switch you can set the search path for libraries: `make LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/your/SDL`.

It may be the that the SDL binary you grabbed from Ubuntu may still not work, due to an incompatible version etc. In that case I suggest downloading and building SDL yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried your suggestion. I see the added flag into the output. But, the new search path doesn't come out in the "searched" directories. Is the path I need to add the one with .so files, or which?

Comment: Yes, the path is the one to the .so files. Does it compile when you set LDFLAGS?

Comment: I have discovered that the libSDL.so is 32-bit when my machine is 64-bit. So, I have done some changes, compiled a new libSDL.a & libSDL.so, and copied them into my "make" folder. Now, I see the "./" path in the search paths when it compiles. However, when I "file -L ./libSDL.so" I notice that even the newly compiled libSDL.so is 32-bit and not 64-bit!! How so I ask the "make" for the libSDL.so to compile them into 64-bit and not 32-bit?

Comment: I just learned that the debian our server "does not provide 64-bit compilation".
Do you know the option in which I can add to the "make" command to compile in 32-bit?

Comment: I have found it: make BASE_CFLAGS=-m32