# SDL DevC++ Linker Issue

Tags: c++, sdl, dev-c++

I started the lazyfoo SDL Tutorials(http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/devcpp/index.php) and i followed the install instructions exactly as written but when i compile this -->

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
   //Start SDL
   SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

   //Quit SDL
   SDL_Quit();

   return 0;    
}
```

This happens -->

> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   skipping incompatible C:/SDL-1.2.15/lib/libSDLmain.a when searching for -lSDLmain
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   skipping incompatible C:/SDL-1.2.15/lib\libSDLmain.a when searching for -lSDLmain
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   skipping incompatible C:/SDL-1.2.15/lib/libSDLmain.a when searching for -lSDLmain
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   cannot find -lSDLmain
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   skipping incompatible C:/SDL-1.2.15/lib/libSDL.dll.a when searching for -lSDL
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   skipping incompatible C:/SDL-1.2.15/lib/libSDL.dll.a when searching for -lSDL
>
> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   cannot find -lSDL
>
> C:\SDL Tutorial Projects\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

I have `DevC++ 5.4.1` and im trying to install `SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar.gz`

Does this have anything to do with my problem?

I've tried everything and it just says skipping incompatible for `libSDLmain.a` and `libSDL.dll.a`.

Comment: You might be mixing up 32 and 64 bit version of libs or it could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925926/skipping-incompatible-libsdl-a-when-searching-for-lsdl

Comment: I have 64bit Windows and there isnt a 64bit version of SDL Development  Library on their website but in the instructions it says its ok if you put SDL.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: I am not an expert on SDL, but I believe that sdl.dll should go to SysWOW64 only if it is a 32-bit version of the dll, and you are builting 32-bit version of executable

Answer (score 0):

> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe
>   skipping incompatible C:/SDL-1.2.15/lib/libSDLmain.a when searching
>   for -lSDLmain

You may have incompatible binaries. Why are you using a x64 compiler? Try installing [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) and compiling with raw gcc.

If you try that, add MinGW/bin to your path and run `gcc 'filelocation' -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL`

Or try using a x86 version of Dev. Also IIRC `-lSDLmain` should come before `-lSDL` and on Windows you need to add `-lmingw32` for it to link and work properly.

If all this fails, one sure way would be to grab same MinGW and use msys to compile [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15.zip) yourself.. just change into the directory and run

```
./configure
mingw32-make
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install Dev-C++ with MinGW for 32 bits and use this option to work with SDL